# How do I get Windows to recognize my simulated mouse click dragging?

Tags: python, mouse, pywin32, pyautogui, pynput

I created a Python script that controls the mouse.  I've used three different libraries, pynput, pyautogui, and py32win (using winapis directly).  All three fail to perform drag actions on a windows app.

I've tried Microsoft Paint and Microsoft Photos and would have the mouse drag the zoom slider back and forth or the rotate image slider back and forth respectively.

I researched the problem myself and my understanding so far is that there is some security layer that's preventing simulated mouse dragging to be sent to whatever event handler for the app.  But I got lost in the weeds on how to solve the problem.

Oddly, mouse-clicking works, but at the same time, any mouse hover states that are supposed to occur also don't register.

Is there a safe and straightforward workaround?  I want to be able to automate routines on a Windows application.  dragging works within a web browser window fine, but when it is a Windows app, it doesn't work.

Thank you!!
Method 1:

```
pyautogui.dragTo(x, y)
```

Method 2:

```
pyautogui.mouseDown(x, y)
pyautogui.moveTo(x, y)
pyautogui.mouseUp(x, y)
```

Neither worked.  I also did the equivalent using Winapi. This didn't work either.

```
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, win32api.GetCursorPos()[0], win32api.GetCursorPos()[1], win32con.VK_LBUTTON, 0)
win32api.SetCursorPos((x, y))
win32api.mouse_event(win32con.MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, win32api.GetCursorPos()[0], win32api.GetCursorPos()[1], win32con.VK_LBUTTON, 0)
```

Comment: Make a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: That's what I did.  I used MS Paint.  I had the mouse drag the zoom slider back and forth, but it won't grab the slider knob.  Same thing when I tried on MS Photos app.  Dragging on a web browser interface works without a problem.

Comment: pyautogui.dragTo(x, y)  is what I used.

Comment: **Post** a [mcve] with a description to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following example using Pyautogui's built-in dragTo is functional for me:

```py
import pyautogui

# Move the mouse to the starting position
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100)

# Drag the mouse to the ending position
pyautogui.dragTo(200, 200, duration=1.5)
```

...but if for some odd reason only clicking the mouse and moving it works for you, you could see if this example works:

```py
import pyautogui

# Move the mouse to the starting position
pyautogui.moveTo(100, 100)

# Click and hold the left mouse button
pyautogui.mouseDown()

# Drag the mouse to the ending position
pyautogui.moveTo(200, 200, duration=1.5)

# Release the left mouse button
pyautogui.mouseUp()
```

Comment: What program did u use to test the mouse on?  was it a windows app or web browser?

Comment: I tried this method on ms paint or ms photos, but it wouldn't drag.  It would work within a web browser no problem, but I'm looking for a solution for using on Windows standalone applications.

Comment: @David I tried out both methods on MS Paint as well as Chrome, and everything worked fine. Could it be something to do with your permissions on Windows maybe? I've seen a weird case before where somebody couldn't use the mouse functions from Pyautogui unless they had the terminal window focused. Something to do with the company's security stuff.

Comment: could be. i never thought of that. I use Windows 11. Do you use Win 11?

Comment: @David I run Windows 10.